# How to display school ID in the textfield?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, field, nested-documents

I want to display the school id in a textfield of a certain view controller but I can't for some reason. I have a function that gets the school ID, of the current School user, and I am able to display it in an alertVC but not a regular VC. I will add images and explanations.

First, I will show my code for the function that gets the school ID for the current user and displays it in the alertVC.

```
  func getTheSchoolsID() -> String {
    db.collection("school_users").whereField("userID", isEqualTo: user?.uid).getDocuments { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("There was an error fetching the documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            self.skoolsID = querySnapshot!.documents.map { document in
                return SchoolID(schoolID: (document.get("school_id") as! String ?? ""))
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    let fixID = "\(skoolsID)"
    let substring = fixID.dropFirst(28).dropLast(3)
    let realString = String(substring)
    
    return realString
}
```

Here is the code for the alertVC as well.

```
@IBAction func infoPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    var text = UITextField()
    
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "User Info", message: "School ID", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .cancel) { (action) in
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    alert.addTextField { (alertTextField) in
        alertTextField.text = self.getTheSchoolsID()
        alertTextField.isEnabled = false
       
        
        
    }
    alert.addAction(action)
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

These two produce this outcome.
[image: Positive Outcome]

This is the exact school_id that is in the document as well.

Now, when I want to display this exact same value in a textfield of the other VC where I add a new event, it shows nothing.

[image: Negative Outcome]

The code is exactly the same as the first code snippet, except for reloadData(), which makes sense, and It doesn't produce the same outcome.

```
func getTheSchoolID() -> String {
    db.collection("school_users").whereField("userID", isEqualTo: user?.uid).getDocuments { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("There was an error fetching the documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            self.skoolID = querySnapshot!.documents.map { document in
                return SchoolID(schoolID: (document.get("school_id") as! String ?? ""))
            }
        }
    }

   
    
    let fixedID = "\(skoolID)"
    let substring = fixedID.dropFirst(28).dropLast(3)
    let realString = String(substring)
    return realString
}
```

Here is me trying to declare it as well.

```
   public override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    errLabel.alpha = 0
    
    getTheSchoolID()
    
    
    
    schoolIDTextF.text = getTheSchoolID()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

If anybody can help with this problem it would be greatly appreciated. I tried to explain it as best as I possibly could. I know there's a lot of information, but if you still need more I can clarify in the comments. Thanks.

Comment: Database access works asynchronously. You have to refactor `getTheSchoolID()` and add a completion handler. It's not possible to `return` the received string.

Comment: Can you possibly just add a code snippet of what you're talking about? @vadian

Comment: In the function itself: `func getTheSchoolID(completion: @escaping (String)->Void) {...`

Comment: Okay thanks @vadian

Comment: So what would the parameter be when im declaring the function? @vadian

Comment: There is no parameter, call `completion()` inside the closure instead of returning the string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228117/discussion-between-dsonawave-and-vadian).

Comment: Please search for swift firebase completion handler. There are many, many examples.

Comment: I still do not understand even after reading the examples. The code is way too advanced and completely different from what I want to do, can you just post an answer using my example? @vadian

Comment: Sorry I'm not particularly familiar with Firebase.

Comment: @dsonawave Please check my answer.

Comment: Hey @Hitesh, already figured it out for a while now, but thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GetSchoolIds from the firestore collection is the asynchronous task. So using the closure you can achieve this.

```
  func getTheSchoolsID(completion:@escaping(_ schoolIds:[SchoolID]?) -> Void) {
        db.collection("school_users").whereField("userID", isEqualTo: user?.uid).getDocuments { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("There was an error fetching the documents: \(err)")
                completion(nil)
            } else {
                let schoolsId = querySnapshot!.documents.map { document in
                    return SchoolID(schoolID: (document.get("school_id") as! String ?? ""))
                }
                completion(schoolsId)
            }
        }
    }
```

Use this function to your VC

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    errLabel.alpha = 0
    
    getTheSchoolsID(completion: {
       [weak self] schoolIds in
        if let schoolIdObj = schoolIds?.first {
        let substring = schoolIdObj.schoolID.dropFirst(28).dropLast(3)
        let realString = String(substring)

          DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self?.schoolIDTextF.text = realString 
          }
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in the async Firebase code. Use closures or completion handler to get the result.

Modify your **getSchoolId** as

```
    func getTheSchoolID(completion: @escaping ((String?) -> ())) {
        db.collection("school_users").whereField("userID", isEqualTo: user?.uid).getDocuments { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("There was an error fetching the documents: \(err)")
                completion(nil)
            } else {
                self.skoolID = querySnapshot!.documents.map { document in
                    return SchoolID(schoolID: (document.get("school_id") as! String ?? ""))
                }
            }
        }
        
        let fixedID = "\(skoolID)"
        let substring = fixedID.dropFirst(28).dropLast(3)
        let realString = String(substring)
        completion(realString)
    }
```

And in your VC, use it as

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    errLabel.alpha = 0
    
    getTheSchoolID(completion: {
       [weak self] schoolId in
        if let id = schooldId {
          DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self?.schoolIDTextF.text = id 
          }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: for some reason it still doesn't work. @udbhateja An error also showed up so I put `@escaping` before the parameter value.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I am editing my response.

Comment: No worries. @udbhateja

Comment: Still no luck. Thanks for trying to help though. @Ronak